# YouTube live on googlecast custom receiver

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, youtube-iframe-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

Is there any solution to play YouTube live video on my Chromecast custom receiver app?

The YouTube iFrame player API can play a regular YouTube video but it does not play Live videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast SDK does not provide any APIs for that.